# Storing 1000+ images inside iPad's storage

Tags: ios, object

I'm working with is some kind of catalog app for iPad (only) for my client's company. They has 1000+ of products. Each product can has more than one image. Each product can be set from the web service whether to display on the app or not. So, for example, outdate product's data and images will not existing inside the app. When my client's decided to synchronize data with the web service. All data will be refresh, all images will be downloaded. Any outdated data or unused has to be deleted.

The thing is, he wanted this app to work offline even without internet connection.

Storing all the product's data is fine as I pull all data in JSON format from web service and parse them as a NSMutableDictionary object. Even they will contains data of 1000+ products, It should be fine (I guess).

But for the images, I have no idea how should I keep them inside the device storage and the best way to referencing each of them. Each image should has a size of 10Kb or less.

My current approach (that I can think of) is to

- Store all product's data inside NSMutableDictionary and the use NSArchiver's method, archiveRoodObject:toFile (or maybe just use [NSMutableDictionary writeToFile:atomically])
- Store all images inside device storage somehow.
- Create an array/dictionary contains all existing images name and path to be used as a reference and store it with NSArchiver (or maybe just use [NSMutableDictionary writeToFile:atomically] too). Any image that isn't inside this reference after the synchronization will be deleted.

That was the approach I did before with my previous client's project. But that project's app contains less than hundred images. And, I feel like I was doing it the wrong way.

So, if you have any good suggestion, please let me know. Any suggestion are welcome.

**Note :** I read some closed topic about storing image into CoreData. But, I don't really want to try it now since I don't have any experience with it before and this current project has tight schedule. So, if it's not really needed, I'd love to try it later.

**Finally**

I decided to go as graver said, migrating my app to use CoreData. But, I might try to store all product's information by using writeToFile first to see how it goes. As graver said, it isn't bad to try something new. Eventually, we will get something.

Comment: Your current approach is fine.  Core data is probably overkilled to use just to store the product's data (using a single table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only change is with CoreData. Keep the product details and the local path of the images in the database, but the actual picture files in the storage, ie. a directory inside your app's Documents directory. CoreData provides you performance you can never achieve archiving all the data. And if you have no experience with CoreData, I think you'll save time reading the docs and implementing it, than thinking about complex solutions with archiving, keeping files track and so on.. And you will get experienced with CoreData for the next project :) 2-in-1

Comment: Yes, but use the `NSCachesDirectory` instead of `NSDocumentDirectory`

Comment: Hmm, isn't only the Documents & Library directories that are guaranteed to be preserved after an app update?

Comment: Even not in update, whenever iOS feels the crunch of space it will delete the data from NSCacheDirectory. So it's not recommended to store the persistent data in the Cache directory.

Comment: Thanks for brough that up, I'm aware of performance too. But the question is, does they are really difference between storing all references into a file and CoreData. I'm respect your answer. But, I've to be sure before I decided to migrate this project to use CoreData.

Comment: Btw, I like the reason you told me why I should use CoreData : )

Comment: It has never been a good practice to save big blobs in a database. It's slows it down as the database file gets bigger...

Comment: @graver One of my apps was rejected because of storing into documents. actually I did this before, but when Apple came up with iCloud they changed their policy. Official statement in  my rejection was (shorted): "Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the /Documents directory [...] Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in the /Library/Caches directory. Examples of files you should put in the Caches directory include[...]content, such as that used by magazine[...]"

Comment: @Kai that makes sense, the bad thing is you can't rely on the fact that your resource exists, but you have to check every time and recreate it... As for this case these are thousands of images, which will consume time in every recreation...

Comment: @Kai that mean I have to store all images inside the cache directory to avoid rejection from Apple. But, I can't avoid losing some cache data when the user switch to use other app? (I'm not quite understand about iCloud and policy changed yet)

Comment: @graver I don't know the details about the offline 'guarantee' in this case, but what I'd do anyway is a lazy load of images. Whenever an image is needed, first look on hard disk and if it's not there load from the internet and store it.

Comment: @Kai yes, that's the usual practice, what I am saying is that already lazy fetched resource could not be considered as cached forever after :P

Comment: @Kai anyway, it's good to know that Apple had changed that. Thanks :)

Comment: I would also suggest using the "Allows External Storage" option for binary data in a Core Data database.  That way, you can just tell core data to store your big image, and it will manage the data.  If it's small enough, it will put it in the database.  Otherwise, it will save the file someplace, and store a link in the database.  All  this happens behind the scenes, and you don't have to worry about it.  Also, I don't think you have to use the caches directory.  You can store your database anywhere in the Library hierarchy (can even create your own subdirectory in there).

Comment: Thanks, Jody. I'll try, sounds nice. : )

Comment: @JodyHagins yes, this is a great option, but unfortunately it's available only in iOS 5.0+